# How do I get my program to accept any case when I enter a word into it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program where a starting sentence is displayed and the user has to input a  word that is in the sentence, so that the program can tell the user the position the word is in the sentence. I want the program to accept every case but at the moment it only accepts UPPER case. Can someone please help me on how to make it case insensitive and still tell the user the positions of the words when they input them? Thanks :)

Here is my code so far:

```
import time

sentence = ("ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY")

sentence2 = sentence.split()

print(sentence)

time.sleep(1)

word = input("Enter Word: ")

print(word)

sentence == sentence.lower()

word == word.lower()

if word in sentence:

    print("Word is valid")

elif word not in sentence:

    print("Word is invalid")


for (num, x) in enumerate(sentence2):

    if word == x:

       print ("Your word is in position ",num+1,"!")
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `==` comparisons for which their value goes right into the void?

Comment: When I only use 1 =, the program doesn't give me the position of the word inputted so that is why I use ==

Comment: But you see how `x == True` does nothing. `=` is the *assignment* operator, while `==` is the *equality* operator.

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator checks for equivalency, it doesn't assign anything. This line of code: `sentence == sentence.lower()` should be `sentence = sentence.lower()` and the line under that should be `word = word.lower()`.

In addition, since you split `sentence` into `sentence2` at the very beginning of the program, `sentence.lower()` does not change `sentence2`, meaning it will never get the position of the word because `sentence2` is all uppercase and `word` is all lowercase. To fix this, get rid of `sentence2` and replace your last for statement with something like this

```
for (num, x) in enumerate(sentence.split()):
```

Comment: Where shall I put it in my code/what shall I replace in my code?

Comment: I said it explicitly in my answer, `sentence == sentence.lower()` and `word == word.lower()` are your offending lines

Comment: But when I use only 1 = , the program doesn't give me the position of the word inputted at the end

Comment: What should I do now then?

Comment: Do you mean change sentence2 to just sentence or completely delete it?

Comment: @J.W As I specified in my answer yet again, delete it

Answer (score 0):

Convert `word` to uppercase with `word = word.lower()`  and remove the following lines:

```
sentence == sentence.lower()
word == word.lower()
```

Comment: But when I only use 1 =, the program doesn't give me the position of the word inputted

Comment: @J.W, what? `N == N.lower()` checks whether `N` is equal to `N` converted to lowercase.

Comment: When I do ,sentence = sentence.lower()  and word = word.lower() the program doesn't give me the position of the word inputted at the end

Comment: @J.W, now I understand. Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the most straightforward way I can think of

```
>>> import collections
>>> position_index = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
>>> for index, word in enumerate(sentence.split()):
...     position_index[word].append(index)
...
>>> position_index["can".upper()]
[5, 12]
>>> position_index["what".upper()]
[2, 10]
```

The for loop builds a dictionary-like data structure that looks like this

```
{'DO': [6, 13], 'WHAT': [2, 10], 'FOR': [7, 14], 'COUNTRY': [4, 16], 'ASK': [0, 9], 'CAN': [5, 12], 'NOT': [1], 'YOU': [8, 11], 'YOUR': [3, 15]}
```

Now that you have a dictionary you need to handle words that are not present as well.  Because this uses a defaultdict you get the added benefit that direct lookups on missing indexes will return an empty list.

```
>>> print(position_index["they".upper()])
[]
```

So you can simply

```
>>> word = "what"
>>> positions = position_index[word.upper()]
>>> if positions:
...     print("The word '%s' appears at position(s): %s" %(word, ",".join(map(str, positions)),))
... else:
...     print("The word '%s' does not appear" %(word,))
...
The word 'what' appears at position(s): 2, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def findPos(sentence, word):
sentence = sentence.lower().split(' ')
word = word.lower()
index = 0
for i in sentence:
    if word == i:
        print '%s is a valid word and is found at position %s'%(word, index)
        return
    index += 1
    print i
print '%s is not a valid word'%word

sentence = 'Ask not what you can do... I forgot!!'
word = raw_input('What is your word?: ')
findPos(sentence, word)
```

Currently this will not work for things that end in punctuation (forgot, do). This is because we directly evaluate the two. The only way I see around that is to do the `in` operator. This of course will give way to even larger issues, (Input:a Output:Ask, what, can. This is because 'a' is technically in all three!)! Hope this helps! This also only returns the first index of the word. This could be modified by having a list of positions. At the end of the loop if `len(list) > 0` we `return`, bypassing the second print. It's up to you!